# Remove two physical drives from raid 5 array (4 disks)

Tags: vmware-esxi, hard-drive, hp, raid5, safe-remove

I'm using a G6 hp server with 4 physical drives and p410 raid controller. I set up raid5 array with 3 physical drives,but one of them has been failed and becouse of this, I am in the *Interim recovery mode* now.

recently, I added the last disk (by mistake!) to the array by this command:

```
hpacucli ctrl slot=0 ld 1 add drives=allunassigned
```

But *I didn't expand my datastore space*. Now, I want to remove the last disk from raid 5 array.

[image]
[image]

Is there any way to remove the last disk and reduce the space of logical drive safety?

[image: hpacucli ctrl all show config]

I would appreciate any help.

Comment: Please show the contents of `hpacucli ctrl all show config`.

Comment: @ewwhite: thanks for your reply, I updated the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you messed up.

In this case, you added a drive to the HP "Array", which redistributed your data across all of the disks.

You didn't specify when you added the disk and when the drive failed, but at some point, you need to replace the 146GB disk.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Ok I will replace the disk but can I reduce number of array to 3 after replacing the disk?

Comment: No, you cannot.